# UItableView with only one section sticky

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which there are lot of sections. If I make the UITableView type as plain all section stick to the top while scrolling.

My requirement is to stick only header for section zero and other headers should float (like when u set the style as group).

Also Note my TableView is having the functionality of collapse and expand which I did using the sections.

My UItableView style is set to plain

```
public enum UITableViewStyle : Int {
    case plain // regular table view
}
```

I have implemented custom section header using

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Any hint in right direction is highly appreciated

Comment: you can not have some sections sticky and some floating. Rather I would suggest using a different cell as a header for section except the zeroth section.

Comment: Apologies.. I have edit my answer. There was a method which was testing method and forget to remove while writing below answer.

Comment: Do not use private api ever if you want to release your project via app store. Even you pass the review once, your app can be removed anytime. I recommend @hardikparmar's solution.

Comment: checkout my answer @Ekra

Comment: @Ekra did you do it without using private API's?

Answer (score 2):

There is a tricky solution to this situation. I have tried to write the solution in **Swift** but for now i am unable to find the solution but i have achieved the above solution in `Objective-C`.

You need to subclass `UITableView` and expose the private api and override them so you can achieve what you want.

Below is an example TableView.

## MYTableView.h

```
@interface MYTableView : UITableView
@property (assign,nonatomic)BOOL shouldFloatHeader;
@property (assign,nonatomic)BOOL shouldFloatFooter;
- (BOOL)allowsHeaderViewsToFloat;
- (BOOL)allowsFooterViewsToFloat;
@end
```

---

## MYTableView.m

```
@implementation MYTableView
- (BOOL)allowsHeaderViewsToFloat{
    return _ shouldFloatHeader;
}
- (BOOL)allowsFooterViewsToFloat{
    return shouldFloatFooter;
}
@end
```

Now you can use above `TableView` in swift as well. I have run and tested it.

Now to make first section sticky and all others non sticky we need to have some trick here. Below is an illustration.
There is `UITableViewDelegate` method `didEndDisplayingHeader` just implement this method and made toggle `shouldFloatHeader` like this..

## Objective-C

```
-(void)tableView:(MYTableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section >= 1) {
        tableView.shouldFloatHeader = YES;
    }else {
        tableView.shouldFloatHeader = NO;
    }
}
```

---

## Swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: MYTableView, didEndDisplayingHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        if section >= 1 {
            tableView.shouldFloatHeader = true
        }else {
            tableView.shouldFloatHeader = false
        }
    }
```

---

> Using private API's can lead your application to reject in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you can not have some sections sticky and some floating. Rather I would suggest using a different cell as a header for each sections except the zeroth section. For zeroth section only you should use the section header view. Make the tableview style as Plain only.